# Write data to text file while skipping blank rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the macro below to write a selected range (in Excel) to a .txt file.

```
Sub ExportTXT()

Dim myFile As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cellValue As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\sales.txt"
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(10, 4))

Open myFile For Output As #1

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value

            If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
                Write #1, cellValue
            Else
                Write #1, cellValue,
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

Close #1

End Sub
```

I'm trying to skip rows 3 and 9.
[image]

Current output - the lines circled in red are the lines that shouldn't be written to the txt file.
[image]

How do I skip blank rows?

I've tried using **Isempty(cellValue) = True ** and empty string **""** conditional statements.

My txt file output should look like this
[image]

Any ideas on how to check the cellValue contents to see if it's empty and write only rows with data.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your code a little bit

```
Sub ExportTXT()

Const DELIMITER = ","

Dim myFile As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cellValue As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim sngRow As Range
Dim vDat As Variant    

    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\sales.txt"
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(10, 4))
    End With

    Dim noCol As Long
    noCol = rng.Columns.Count    

    Open myFile For Output As #1

    For Each sngRow In rng.Rows

        vDat = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(sngRow))
        vDat = Join(vDat, DELIMITER)
        If Len(vDat) >= noCol Then
            Write #1, vDat
        End If

    Next

    Close #1

End Sub
```

**Update** Based on one of the comments use the follwoing statement in order to avoid "text qualification"

```
Print #1, vDat
```

instead of

```
Write #1, vDat
```

Comment: You might have changed it to "broken". The `Write` statement doesn't just comma delimit the output - it also text qualifies strings (albeit poorly).

Comment: @Comintern: Not sure what you mean but that's probably because of my command of English.

Comment: NP - If you have a string - `x = "foo"` and use `Write #1, x`, it will wrap it in double quotes in the text file.  You'll get `"foo"` instead of simply `foo`.  Using `Join` beforehand will wrap the *entire line* in double quotes. Run your code and look at the output - you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Ah, I see, but that can be fixed easily by using Print, right?

Comment: If it doesn't need the double quotes around strings, yes. It would mainly depend on the OP's output spec. `Write` was designed to be read with `Input` - `Print` doesn't do the formatting.  In either case, it's a good idea to escape things like `,`, `"`, etc. in strings, but the OP's data looks fairly simple.